# Fetching current path of the file using Ansible

Tags: path, ansible

In Ansible, i need to take a parent directory or current path of file automatically, in some of chef framework we have chef::config,it ll take automatically file path.

```
e.g:
  /tasks/main.yml:

    name: execute cmd
    command: python file.py
```

If I have my "file.py" in a tasks folder, I need to execute my playbook from that path only like: /home/playbook/roles/sample/tasks ,then only it taking a script file and running.Suppose when i run from root path i mean /home/playbook/ path,it shows "No such file or directory"

I have tried lookup(env,HOME), It just takes /home alone but not related to that file path.

So to take a current file path how to give in ansible???

Thanks

Comment: I suspect you try to do something wrong. What do you want to achieve? Ansible is expected to run tasks on remote hosts. If you need to execute your script there, you should copy it in advance or use `script` module.

Comment: So script module automatically takes path of my python script file and run it ????

Comment: `script` module will copy the file first and then run it. if you use roles, you should place scripts into `roles/my_role/files` folder.

Comment: thanks Suvorov.....it works

Answer (score 2):

Answer from comments

> `script` module will copy the file first and then run it. if you use roles, you should place scripts into `roles/my_role/files` folder.

Comment: the script module only handles shell scripts, this question is about a python script.

Comment: @smiller171 you can execute arbitrary scripts as long as you specify correct shebang. Just add `#!/usr/bin/env python` to the beginning of your py-script and it will be successfully executed.